# GlassFish JDBC authentication with postgres. Can't log in to the application

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp, glassfish, payara

I'm trying to make authentication with Payara, using Postgres 9.4. I've been following some tutorials but they don't work. I create a database, populate it, remember to hash the passwords (using MD-5), then a JDBC connection pool (ping works), then jdbc resources, a realm, next I create an java web application, I remember about web.xml, glassfish-web.xml, about login and error page.... and after deploying the application and trying to log in, I get an error page (the one that I created in the application).

Here's exactly what I do:

I created a database called "security":

```
CREATE TABLE "Group" (
    group_id serial  NOT NULL,
    group_name text  NOT NULL,
    user_id int  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Group_pk PRIMARY KEY (group_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Users (
    user_id serial  NOT NULL,
    username text  NOT NULL,
    password text  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Users_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

ALTER TABLE "Group" ADD CONSTRAINT Group_Users
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES Users (user_id)  
    NOT DEFERRABLE 
    INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
;
```

I used an encryption website to encrypt my password, "test", and got the following value:
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6. I used that value to populate my database:

I use Payara Server.
I create new JDBC connection pool, like on the picture. I get info " Ping Succeeded", so I assume this is part is ok.

I create a JDBC Resource, with JNDI Name: jdbc/simplesec, and Pool Name: secuPool.

I create a new realm, called "secuRealm" - pictures below. I suppose something may be wrong there?
[realm part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3foM.png)
[realm part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDz3j.png)
Next, I write the application part. (I select web application, java).
glassfish-web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <group-name>admin</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>guest</role-name>
    <group-name>guest</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>secuRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

login.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action="j_security_check" method="POST">
            Username:<input type="text" name="j_username"/><br/>
            Password:<input type="password" name="j_password" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            <br/>            
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

error.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Incorrect Credentials</h1>
        Try again. <br/>
        <a href="login.jsp">Login</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.jsp :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1><br />
        <a href="login.jsp">Login</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

After deploying the application I try to log in. Username: 1, password: test. I get an error.jsp page in response. I don't understand why, using correct user data, I cannot log in. 
Where did I make mistake and how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

try to specify Digest Algorythm: none at the realm settings